# Fixed-size std::span vs std::array

Tags: c++, stl, stdarray, c++20

C++20 includes [`std::span`, which "describes an object that can refer to a contiguous sequence of objects with the first element of the sequence at position zero"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span). Its interface is very close to `std::array`, though it supports dynamic extent as well as fixed one.

The obvious difference is that `std::array` owns its elements (and so its destructor destroys them) and `std::span` doesn't.

Is there anything else `array` can be used for that `span` can't?

Comment: isnt span for a different use-case? I might be wrong, but I think span is like `string_view` for `string`s

Comment: Span is for completely different reasons. Span is basically a safe idiom for C++ dynamic array - incapsulation of a pointer to begin and end of a sequence.

Comment: `span` is to `array` what `string_view` it to `string`. `array` can be used to copy memory around while `span` only manipulates handles to it.

Comment: "Is there anything an `int` can be used for that an `int*` cannot?"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`span` is to `array` as pointers are to values.

Is there anything an `int` can be used for than an `int*` cannot?

If you swept your code base and replaced every `int` with an `int*` you'd have a completely nonsense codebase, even if you added a `*` at every point-of-use of the `int*`.  If you swept your code base and replaced every `std::array` with a `std::span`, the same would be true.

Pointers and values are different things.  You can jump through hoops and try to deal with pointers as if they are the value of the thing they point to, but trying to do so is often difficult, and the result is often incoherent.